# jquery mobile, using controls only?

Tags: jquery-mobile

I am interested in using jquery mobile controls, but only way i can use it is by using "page" tag.

using page does lot of auto injection into html plus links etc goes through ajax for back button. I am not interested in all sort of auto ui.

How can i use just jquery mobile controls(buttons, links, lists etc) without making my whole page jquery mobile page?

Answer (score 3):

From [the jQuery Mobile Alpha 2 release notes](http://jquerymobile.com/2010/11/jquery-mobile-alpha-2-released/):

> ### Global Configuration
>
> jQuery Mobile now has a number of ways to [override the initial configuration](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a2/#docs/api/globalconfig.html) of a number of aspects of the framework (such as disabled Ajax-style links or forms). This can allow you to sculpt jQuery Mobile to work in situations that are more-specialized and don’t fit the complete design methodology of the framework (giving you the ability to only use a couple widgets rather than the framework as whole, for example).

---

So, you can work with jQuery Mobile *à la carte* by disabling the bits you don't want. For example, to disabled the ajaxical navigation and forms:

```
$(document).live("mobileinit", function() {
    $.mobile.ajaxLinksEnabled = false;
    $.mobile.ajaxFormsEnabled = false;
});
```

**N.B.**, as the linked docs page says, you'll need to execute your customizing JavaScript (like the snippet above) *before* the jQuery Mobile is loaded, so import your scripts something like this:

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="custom-scripting.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-mobile.js"></script>
```

Comment: That's nice. I was going to answer more in terms of "no, unless you fiddle with JQM sources itself"

Answer (score 2):

I too wanted to do this. However I was wanting to add controls to a page that was already using jQuery UI so there were some extra steps.

1. Also had to disable ajax handling to get my regular (non jqm) buttons submitting/working properly

   ```
   $(document).live("mobileinit", function() {
       $.extend($.mobile, {
           autoInitializePage: false,
           linkBindingEnabled: false,
           ajaxEnabled: false
       });
   });
   ```
2. JQM and jQuery UI both have a widget named 'button' so one overwrites the other so I changed the JQM widget name to mbutton to stop the collision

   ```
   $.widget("mobile.mbutton", $.mobile.widget, {
   ```
3. In the init code for JQM, stop the hiding of content during render as we have set autoInitializePage = false so we want to avoid the 5 sec timeout to show the page

   ```
   if ($.mobile.autoInitializePage) {
       // Add mobile, initial load "rendering" classes to docEl
       $html.addClass("ui-mobile ui-mobile-rendering");
       // This is a fallback. If anything goes wrong (JS errors, etc), or events don't fire,
       // this ensures the rendering class is removed after 5 seconds, so content is visible and accessible
       setTimeout(hideRenderingClass, 5000);
   }
   ```
4. JQM and JQUI both have ui-icon css that collides, so I added an extra '.ui-mobile' selector into the JQM css in 2 locations:

   ```
   /* Icons
   ----------------------------------------------------*/
   .ui-mobile .ui-icon,
   .ui-mobile .ui-icon-searchfield:after {

   ...

   /* Alt icon color
   ----------------------------------------------------*/
   .ui-mobile .ui-icon-alt {
   ```
5. Simply initialize the controls as you would any jQuery UI controls ie:

   ```
   $(".my-slider").slider();
   ```

Disclaimer: I have only used the slider as a toggle switch so far so there will probably be more css and js to patch, and I needed to do a few custom css tweaks to re-position the slider in its track.

HTH anyone else looking to do the same.

Answer (score 0):

Jquery Mobile has added a builder where you can pick and choose exactly which pieces to include:

http://jquerymobile.com/download-builder/